# Cannot set CURRENT OPTIMIZATION HINT special register via db2dsdriver.cfg <specialregisters> section

Tags: db2, zos

I was trying to provide a default value for the CURRENT OPTIMIZATION HINT special register for my DB2 client application.

I tried db2dsdriver.cfg file and it's  section and JDBC specialRegisters Uri parameter. Both lead to the same result:

1. When I set the value **without quotes** like so:

db2dsdriver.cfg:

```
            <specialregisters>
                <parameter name="CURRENT OPTIMIZATION HINT" value="HELLO1"/>
            </specialregisters>
```

or with JDBC Uri:

```
jdbc:db2://<ip>:<port>/<database>:retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=true;emulateParameterMetaDataForZCalls=1;specialRegisters=CURRENT OPTIMIZATION HINT=HELLO1;
```

I get an exception saying I have a problem with the SET instruction:

> Message: ERROR [42721] [IBM][DB2] SQL0969N  There is no message text corresponding to SQL error "-725" in the message file on this workstation.  The error was returned from module "DSNLXENV" with original tokens "CURRENT QUERY OPTIMIZATION DALLASA".  SQLSTATE=42721

Here is the exempt from the java trace:

```html
...

[jcc][t4] 
[jcc][t4]        SEND BUFFER: SQLSTT                 (ASCII)           (EBCDIC)
[jcc][t4] 0000   0036D04300010030  2414000000002653  .6.C...0$.....&S  ..}.............
[jcc][t4] 0010   4554204355525245  4E54204F5054494D  ET CURRENT OPTIM  ........+..|&..(
[jcc][t4] 0020   495A4154494F4E20  48494E54203D2048  IZATION HINT = H  .!...|+...+.....
[jcc][t4] 0030   454C4C4F31FF                        ELLO1.            .<<|..          
[jcc][t4] 

...

[jcc][Thread:Worker-103][SQLException@d1aed064] java.sql.SQLException
[jcc][Thread:Worker-103][SQLException@d1aed064][Sqlca@a74669be] DB2 SQLCA from server
[jcc][Thread:Worker-103][SQLException@d1aed064][Sqlca@a74669be] SqlCode        = -725
[jcc][Thread:Worker-103][SQLException@d1aed064][Sqlca@a74669be] SqlErrd        = { 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0 }
[jcc][Thread:Worker-103][SQLException@d1aed064][Sqlca@a74669be] SqlErrmc       = CURRENT QUERY OPTIMIZATION;DALLASA
[jcc][Thread:Worker-103][SQLException@d1aed064][Sqlca@a74669be] SqlErrmcTokens = { CURRENT QUERY OPTIMIZATION, DALLASA }
[jcc][Thread:Worker-103][SQLException@d1aed064][Sqlca@a74669be] SqlErrp        = DSNLXENV
[jcc][Thread:Worker-103][SQLException@d1aed064][Sqlca@a74669be] SqlState       = 42721
[jcc][Thread:Worker-103][SQLException@d1aed064][Sqlca@a74669be] SqlWarn        =            
[jcc][Thread:Worker-103][SQLException@d1aed064] SQL state  = 42721
[jcc][Thread:Worker-103][SQLException@d1aed064] Error code = -725
[jcc][Thread:Worker-103][SQLException@d1aed064] Tokens     = CURRENT QUERY OPTIMIZATION;DALLASA
[jcc][Thread:Worker-103][SQLException@d1aed064] Stack trace follows
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: CURRENT QUERY OPTIMIZATION;DALLASA
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kd.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kd.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kd.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.jg.c(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.jg.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.bb.k(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.bb.g(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.p.f(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.readSetGenericSQLSetInfo_(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.qg.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.sg.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.Agent.readPiggybackCommands(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.Agent.beginReadChain(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.beginReadChain(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.Agent.flow(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fp.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fp.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fp.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.datatools.filter.DependencyService.executeCountQuery(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.datatools.filter.DependencyService.access$3(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.datatools.filter.DependencyService$LoadCountsJob.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Unknown Source)
```

2. When I try the same and put **quotes** around the value, I get some strange results:

db2dsdriver.cfg:

```
            <specialregisters>
                <parameter name="CURRENT OPTIMIZATION HINT" value="'HELLO1'"/>
            </specialregisters>
```

or with JDBC Uri:

```
jdbc:db2://<ip>:<port>/<database>:retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=true;emulateParameterMetaDataForZCalls=1;specialRegisters=CURRENT OPTIMIZATION HINT='HELLO1';
```

The result is that the special registed is set to some faulty value:

```
SELECT CURRENT OPTIMIZATION HINT FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

returns a string:

> "\0\0\0\u00010\u001a\0\0"

Here is my environment info:

```html
C:\Windows\system32>db2level
DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable: "DB2")
uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL10012" with level identifier
"0203010E".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v10.1.200.238", "s121127", "IP23389", and Fix
Pack "2".
Product is installed at "C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB" with DB2 Copy Name "DB2COPY1".


C:\Windows\system32>db2set -all
[e] DB2PATH=C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB
[i] DB2_SELECTIVITY=ALL
[i] DB2INSTPROF=C:\ProgramData\IBM\DB2\DB2COPY1
[i] DB2CODEPAGE=1252
[g] DB2_EXTSECURITY=NO
[g] DB2_COMMON_APP_DATA_PATH=C:\ProgramData
[g] DB2PATH=C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB
[g] DB2INSTDEF=DB2

C:\Windows\system32>db2cli validate
IBM DATABASE 2 Interactive CLI Sample Program
(C) COPYRIGHT International Business Machines Corp. 1993,1996
All Rights Reserved
Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [ CLI Driver Version  : 10.01.0000 ]
  [ Informational Tokens: "DB2 v10.1.200.238","s121127","IP23389","Fixpack  2" ]
  [ CLI Driver Type     : IBM Data Server Runtime Client ]
  [ db2diag.log Path    : C:\ProgramData\IBM\DB2\DB2COPY1\DB2\db2diag.log ]
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  IBM Data Server Client packages on the current workstation :

  Copyname      Version     Installed Location
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  DB2COPY1[C,D] 10.01.0002  C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB

  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

db2dsdriver.cfg Schema Validation :
Success: The schema validation operation completed successfully.
The configuration file C:\ProgramData\IBM\DB2\DB2COPY1\cfg\db2dsdriver.cfg is valid

The validation completed.
```

For DDF DB2 access I am using:

- IBM Data Studio 4.1.3 which in turn uses JDBC driver `db2jcc4.jar` version 4.25.1301
- Custom .NET application using `IBM.Data.DB2.dll` version 10.1.2.2

Comment: Edit your post to show the `db2level` output for the Db2-client, or the exact version of *which* client you are using.

Comment: Please download and install a currently supported Db2-client from IBM fix central and then retry. For example, the V11.1.4.4 Db2-client.

Comment: @mao As long as I tried using both the old IBM.Data.DB2 and the new JDBC and see the same behaviour, it does not seem to be the client problem, isn't it?

Comment: If the latest jdbc driver-version ( 3.72.52  (for type 3) or 4.25.1301 (for type 4) gives the same symptom then the issue might not be a jdbc-driver problem.   The -725 code means the special register was supplied an invalid value.  Can you confirm that you can set this special register to the specific-value dynamically at the host database directly (i.e. not using client drivers) ?

Comment: @mao Yes, I confirm that I can successfully apply `CURRENT OPTIMIZATION HINT` via simple SQL command: `SET CURRENT OPTIMIZATION HINT = 'HELLO1'`. Not only the command completes but I can check the value is applied via `SELECT CURRENT OPTIMIZATION HINT FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1` and via the warning 394 I get from PLAN_TABLE instructions.

Comment: Your question update mentions db2jcc4.jar version 4.1.15. Please can you correct this . It should show version 4.21.xxx *or higher*

Comment: Maybe this is one for IBM Support.  I don't see any hit for SQL0725N in the Knowledge Center so not sure what message you are getting back from the z/OS server.  There are hits on IBM Support thou  e.g. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM86663

Comment: @PaulVernon May be so but I don't have an IBM support account. I use an aftermarket z/OS mainframe, no paid account. I've already found the mentioned PM86663, but again, without a support account I don't have access to it.

Comment: @mao I will double check that on Monday, but as far as IBM technote states http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21641858&myns=swgimgmt&mynp=OCSS62YD&mync=E I need the 4.15 driver version

Comment: @mao I've specified the driver version wrong, it's not 4.1.15, it is 4.15, I will try 
 the latest 4.25.1301 though

Comment: Without PM86663, I bet you will need to find an alternative approach, as it looks like a direct match.

Comment: @mao Tried the same with the latest JDBC driver version I could find `4.25.1301`. All results are the same.